# Where do I put $(this) in the function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Since I want to use classes instead of id's in these functions(I have three of the same function with different things I want to .append) I am sure I need to put $(this) in those functions somewhere to only trigger only ONE function on button click and not all three of them. but I am not sure because I am a total beginner in jquery/js, so I would appreciate some help.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".onclick").click(function () {
        $('#favorites').append('<div data-role="main"class="ui-content"><div  class="ui-grid-b"><div class="ui-block-a">Arrow</div><div class="ui-block-b">More Info</div><div class="ui-block-c">Unfavorite</div></div></div>');
    });
});
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JYxqEw - HTML And the Jquery Code

Comment: which elements have `.onclick` class? Can you put minimal html code for this question?

Comment: The buttons have the .onclick class, and I want to insert content in to a new page called Favorites(#Favorites)<div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
        <div class="ui-grid-a">
            <div class="ui-block-a" id="a1"><strong>ARROW</strong></div>
                <div class="ui-block-b"><button  class="onclick">Favorite</button></div>
        </div>
</div>

Comment: there is no element in your html code holding id=favorites so nothing happens. Can you put your html code by editing your question not by commenting?

Comment: this will be helpful in addition to the answer. http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_selectors.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$('.onclick')` selects all the elements with a class of `onclick`. That means that, whenever something with `class="onclick"` is clicked, that function will fire.

If you want all of those elements to append that exact HTML to the `#favorites` element, then you can leave your code as-is.

However, if what you're trying to do is append that html to the clicked element, that is when you'd use `$(this)` -- that selects the element you clicked with jQuery, then you can append directly to that element ie:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".onclick").click(function () {
        // this will append the HTML to the element that triggered the click event.
        $(this).append('<div data-role="main"class="ui-content"><div  class="ui-grid-b"><div class="ui-block-a">Arrow</div><div class="ui-block-b">More Info</div><div class="ui-block-c">Unfavorite</div></div></div>');
    });
});
```

**EDIT**

so to insert the contents of each `.onclick` into `#favorites`, you'll need to use the `innerHTML` value of the DOM node. example fiddle:

http://jsbin.com/qazepubuzu/edit?html,js,output

When you select something with jQuery, you're actually getting back not just the DOM node, but a jQuery object -- this object contains both a reference to the actual DOM node (`[0]`), as well as a jquery object (`[1]`).

So to select the DOM node with `$(this)`, you target the node: `$(this)[0]`. Then you can use `.innerHTML()` to grab the HTML contents of the node and do as you like.

Final result:

```
$(function () {
  $('.onclick').click(function () {
    $('#favorites').append( $(this)[0].innerHTML );
  });
});
```

Comment: Since I have three buttons with different content I want to append to the Favorites page I need a solution where I can click the button and only the actual content related to that button is added to the favorites page, and I wish to do that by using the .onclick class, another way I found that works is just using the ID's, but I just want to work out how I can do it with classes

Answer (score 0):

So the building blocks are not that complex, but I think you're a novice jQuery developer and so you may not be clear on the difference between jQuery and JS yet.

`$(selector, context)` allows us to create a jQuery collection for a CSS `selector` which is the child of a current `context` DOM node, though if you do not specify one there is an automatic one (which is `document.body`, I think). Various functions iterating over jQuery collections make the particular element available as `this` within the JavaScript. To get to the `strong` element from the `.onclick` element in the HTML fragment you need to travel up in the hierarchy, then to the appropriate element. Then, we can collect the text from the element. We can do this in either JS or jQuery.

To do this with simply jQuery:

```js
// AP style title case, because Chicago is too crazy.
var to_title_case = (function () { // variable scope bracket
    var lower_case = /\b(?:a|an|the|and|for|in|so|nor|to|at|of|up|but|on|yet|by|or)\b/i,
        first_word = /^(\W*)(\w*)/,
        last_word = /(\w*)(\W*)$/;
    function capitalize(word) {
        return word.slice(0, 1).toUpperCase() + word.slice(1).toLowerCase();
    }
    function capitalize_mid(word) {
        return lower_case.exec(word) ? word.toLowerCase() : capitalize(word);
    }
    return function to_title_case(str) {
        var prefix = first_word.exec(str),
            str_minus_prefix = str.slice(prefix[0].length),
            suffix = last_word.exec(str_minus_prefix),
            center = str_minus_prefix.slice(0, -suffix[0].length);
        return prefix[1] + capitalize(prefix[2]) + center.replace(/\w+/g, capitalize_mid)
                + capitalize(suffix[1]) + suffix[2];
    };
})();

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".onclick").click(function () {
        var text = $(this).parents('.ui-grid-a').find('.ui-block-a').text();
        var html = '<div data-role="main"class="ui-content">'
                 + '<div class="ui-grid-b"><div class="ui-block-a">' 
                 + to_title_case(text) + '</div><div class="ui-block-b">More Info</div>'
                 + '<div class="ui-block-c">Unfavorite</div></div></div>';
        $("#favorites").append(html);
    });
});
```